# How to set line spacing of an ordered list consistently across browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list which uses large Georgia for the numbering and smaller Arial font for the text (as recommended at [How to align two columns of text in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112609/how-to-align-two-columns-of-text-in-css)). I am using p tags within the li's so i can set the font size which also sets the associated line height (ensuring that there is normal line spacing if the li's run over more than one line). This is nearly fine, however in firefox the spacing between the bullets is much tighter than any other brower, all others seem to be adding a margin above the p tags despite explicitly setting the margins to 0. When i look at it using developer tools in Chrome it seems to add -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em; to the p tags which are not overridden. This may not be the cause as it also happens in non webkit browsers apart from FF and everything else i've read says these are overridden by setting the margins (which are set in the code below and at the top of my css file with an all element css margin reset). I would be immensely grateful if anyone could point out why I'm getting more spacing on all non FF browsers as I've been trying to work it out for ages and just cannot see why it's happening! FYI I have tried explicitly setting the line heights of each element but this has exactly the same effect. You can see the code below.

Thanks so much for your help and for any advice anyone can give!

Dave

```
ol {
color: #ec008c;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 1.6em;
list-style-position: outside;
font-family: georgia, serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
}

ol li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ol li p {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 10px;
color: #000000;
margin: 0 0 4px 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
}

<div id="playlist">
<div id="playlistinner">
<p id="playlisttitle">The List</p>
<ol>
<li class="listitem"><p><strong>Entry 1</strong> - entry details</p></li>
<li class="listitem"><p><strong>Entry 2</strong> - entry details</p></li>
<li class="listitem"><p><strong>Entry 3</strong> - entry details that are much longer and span more than one line</p></li>
<li class="listitem"><p><strong>Entry 4</strong> - entry details</p></li>
<li class="listitem"><p><strong>Entry 5</strong> - entry details</p></li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with using pixels for padding units?

Comment: Nothing but as it starts with the margins not being equal it doesn't help without using browser specific rules which i want to avoid unless necessary. Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention non-webkit, non-Firefox browsers appear to do the same thing. Have you looked using their developer tools? Both IE (except for 7; 6 has it as an addon; 8 and 9 have it included, just hit F12) and Opera have developer tools. Check them out and see what's causing it in them.

Opera puts a 1em top and bottom margins on the `<p>` element, I don't have a platform that IE runs on, but I assume it does, too. In the code and example you give us, you have no all-element margin reset, so there's nothing to override until you explicitly set the margins.

Another thing you can do is set `line-height: 1;` to tighten things up farther.

Aso, have you considered restructuring a little? From what you've posted here, your content might be better suited to a [definition list.](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/)

On a side note, why are you using frames? Not only are they being deprecated in HTML5, but there are [several major reasons why](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/frames/goodorbad.html) they are bad. If you want to have a single file for universal stuff, such as headers and navigation, then have a look at server side includes.

Comment: I checked via developer tools in IE previously and the styles listed match those that i have specified and 'should' work (well according to me anyway!) I'm actually not using frames its just the URL shortener is adding them, i'm completely with you about never using them! With the li lineheight set opera now matches FF, and IE and Chrome have slightly wider spacing. I suspect this is because of the text rendering but there does still seem to be a slightly larger margin above the span/p in chrome/IE when looking in dev tools (but the styles listed are now correct)

Comment: And i also meant to say i'm using * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } to reset the margins/padding on all elements but I forgot to put it in the linked test doc (i've added it now) :) I would be interested to see if you think the discrepancy that is remaining is just due to how the browsers render the text or if there is still an issue? I will also have a look at definition lists, i'd never heard of them before but they look very interesting. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @deshg - From what I can tell, it looks like your numbers are the culprit. Comparing Chrome and Opera on MacOS, it looks like one holds a bit more space for the numbers, since they are slightly larger than the lines of text and the margin when there's only one line of text. Try either adding margins or adjusting your line-height so line-height plus margins matches the font-size of the numerals (or making your numerals smaller).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it could be connected to the line-height of larger font you use in the `li` element. If I add `line-height: 12px` to the `li`-style in Chrome, the spacing looks the same as in FF.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried this previously and you are totally right it looks much better (I have updated the link above) however there is still a small descrepancy between FF/Opera and the other browsers.I suspect this may now be due to the text rendering on different engines,but there does still seem to be a tiny extra margin above my p/span tags in non FF/Opera browsers (which is more apparent with more list items). FYI I also added the margin reset which I forgot to add previously!Do you think the remaining difference is just down to rendering? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @deshg I saw that you set the margin/padding for `p` to 0 in your example. Honestly I have no idea where the remaining difference might come from if not differences in rendering or how line-height inheritance is interpreted. Seeing how differently IE Browsers render text sometimes compared to other browsers (e.g. the Euro sign), i would not be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

@deshg; first i want to say that use [resetsheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/). Now the problem is that there is an extra spacing between li in chrome

**REASON**

1) each **user-agent** have there own default properties . So, they rendered differently.

2) May be is a structural also for more check [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) .

**solutions**

a. use resetsheet.

b. better to give span instead of p.

c. As svanelten said give `line-height` in your `li` for more check the links

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

[Spacing differences between IE7 and Firefox/Opera/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561007/spacing-differences-between-ie7-and-firefox-opera-chrome)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am using * {  margin: 0; padding: 0; } to reset the margins/padding on all elements but I forgot to put it in the linked test doc (i've added it now). I can see the more detailed cssreset obviously resets all possible defaults but presumably in this case the * {  margin: 0; padding: 0; } would suffice? Thanks so much for your help.